# Save an image for each contact in a datagrid control using wcf service?

Tags: c#, database, wcf, silverlight, datagrid

In a C# silverlight application I've got a datagrid control that gets contact details from an sql database table. I can add new details to the datagrid by typing in the textboxes and clicking the add button. there is an upload button to upload an image in the Image control and works fine. but I can't seem to save an image for each contact in the table and veiw it along with the other information using wcf service.

here is what I've wrote in my upload image button:

```
 private void uploadbtn_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "JPEG files|*.jpg";
        //openFileDialog.Filter = "Images (*.jpg, *.png, *.bmp)|*.jpg;*.png;*.bmp";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            Stream stream = (Stream)openFileDialog.File.OpenRead();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.SetSource(stream);
            MyImage.Source = bi;
            string fileName = openFileDialog.File.Name;

        }
    }
```

in my add contact button I have :

```
    ServiceReference1.Contact contact = new ServiceReference1.Contact();
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client connection = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        connection.InsertContactCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.InsertContactCompletedEventArgs>(connection_InsertContactCompleted);
        contact.ConName = txtname.Text;
        contact.ConNumber = txtnumber.Text;
        contact.ConDescription = txtdescription.Text;
```

and in the service :

```
      [OperationContract]
       public int InsertContact(Contact cnt)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = " insert into Contact(ConName,    ConNumber,ConDescription) values(@1,@2,@3)";
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =   cnt.ConName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@2", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cnt.ConNumber;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@3", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cnt.ConDescription;
                con.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    return i;
                  }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to add the image to these codes.

Comment: How are you planning on storing the images? Inside a database table? On a file system?

Comment: inside a database table in sql and being able to display it in a datagrid control